# Como caber todo conteúdo na tela? Borda no fim da página não aparece no visor ou navegador

Tags: front-end

Estou tentando criar um layout responsivo ao máximo**, e tenho problemas com o fim da borda da div. Eu propositalmente coloco uma borda vermelha por volta da div, para se der algo errado eu identificar imediatamente. O objetivo é que eu tenha todo o conteúdo da página exibida no dispositivo (seja ele qual for), sem a barra de rolagem, porém exibindo 100 do conteúdo dela (sem necessidade real da rolagem). As duas bordas finais (canto direito e inferior) estão sumindo da tela do dispositivo. Segue o código usado

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.um {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  /* para falta de suporte */
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  /* para Chrome */
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  /* para Firefox */
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  /* para suporte nativo */
}
#containerGeral {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#caixaTeste {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
}
#caixaTeste2 {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
}
#containerTeste {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 30%;
  position: absolute;
}
#containerFilho {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  width: 65%;
  height: 65%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#containerFilho2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  width: 65%;
  height: 65%;
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1 align="center">RELATIVO: CONTAINER GERAL</h1>
    <div id="caixaTeste">ABSOLUTO</div>
    <div id="caixaTeste2">ABSOLUTO</div>
    <div id="containerTeste">NOVO CONTAINER
      <div id="containerFilho">CONTEINER FILHO
        <div id="containerFilho2">CONTAINER FILHO - FILHO</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

** Não acredito que exista nada 100% responsivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione `box-sizing: border-box;` ao seu container externo, `#containerGeral`.

[Da documentação da propriedade box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> A propriedade CSS box-sizing é utilizada para alterar a propriedade padrão da box model, usada para calcular larguras (*widths*) e alturas (*heights*) dos elementos. É possível de usar essa propriedade para emular o comportamento dos navegadores (*browser*) que não suportam corretamente a especificação da propriedade CSS box model.

Versão funcional a seguir:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <style type="text/css">
     html ,
    
    body { margin:0; height: 100%;}
    .um { background: #333; 
     color: white; 
     padding: 50px 20px; 
       height: 100%;                        /* para falta de suporte */  
       height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);  /* para Chrome */
        height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);     /* para Firefox */
       height: calc(100% - 100px);          /* para suporte nativo */
       
     }
    
    #containerGeral
       {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: red;
        background-color: yellow;
       }
    
    #caixaTeste
      {
       width: 15%;
       height: 15%;
       background-color: blue;
       position: absolute;
       top: 0%;
      }
    
    #caixaTeste2
      {
       width: 15%;
       height: 15%;
       background-color: green;
       position: absolute;
       right: 0%;
       top: 0%;
      }
    
    
    #containerTeste
    
      {
       width: 40%;
       height: 40%;
       border-style: solid;
       border-color: red;
       background-color: green;
    
       bottom: 30%;
       position: absolute;
      }
    
    #containerFilho
      {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0%;
       width: 65%;
       height: 65%;
       background-color: #ccc;
      }
    
    
    #containerFilho2
      {
       position: absolute;
       right: 0%;
       width: 65%;
       height: 65%;
       background-color: blue;
       bottom: 0%;
      }
    </style>  
    <title></title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="containerGeral" ><h1 align="center">RELATIVO: CONTAINER GERAL</h1>
       <div id="caixaTeste">ABSOLUTO</div>
       <div id="caixaTeste2">ABSOLUTO</div>
         <div id="containerTeste">NOVO CONTAINER
          <div id="containerFilho">CONTEINER FILHO
           <div id="containerFilho2">CONTAINER FILHO - FILHO</div>
          </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: fica bam assim tmb,, achei que se só manja assembly

Comment: Isso matou a pau! Valeu mesmo!
Essa única linha (box-sizing: border-box;)  mudou tudo

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff Sempre um prazer ajudar!

Answer (score 3):

O que ocorre é que a borda que `#containerGeral` possui está sendo adicionada ao `height` e ao `width` do elemento, então a medida será `100% + a borda`.

Para resolver isso ou você retira a borda ou você muda o `height e width 100%` para `height/width: calc(100% - (a borda))`.

Lembrando que você deve definir a espessura da borda e fazer `x2` no caso de haver tanto a borda direita quanto a esquerda e vale para a borda top e bottom também.

Outro detalhe é que você não está utilizando nenhum `reset`, então sua tag `h1` e outros elementos podem se comportar diferente em diversos navegadores.

Para seu caso específico, você pode colocar :

```
html, body{margin:0; height:100%, padding:0;}
```

e

```
h1{margin:0;}
```

Meu `reset` é basicão :

```
*{margin:0; margin:0;padding:0}
```

Mas existem outros bem famosos que é o caso do [Mayer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Veja como fica:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
     <style type="text/css">
  html,body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
  }
  #containerGeral {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - (4px));
    height: calc(100% - (4px));
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width:2px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  #caixaTeste {
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
  }
        h1{margin:0;}  
  #caixaTeste2 {
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
  }
  #containerTeste {
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 30%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #containerFilho {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    width: 65%;
    height: 65%;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  #containerFilho2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    width: 65%;
    height: 65%;
    background-color: blue;
    bottom: 0%;
  }
     </style>  
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="containerGeral" >
      <h1 align="center">RELATIVO: CONTAINER GERAL</h1>
      <div id="caixaTeste">ABSOLUTO</div>
      <div id="caixaTeste2">ABSOLUTO</div>
      <div id="containerTeste">NOVO CONTAINER
       <div id="containerFilho">CONTEINER FILHO
        <div id="containerFilho2">CONTAINER FILHO - FILHO</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quando uso ...
   height: calc(100% - 100px);
   width: calc(100% - 100px);
fica um espaço em branco. 
Quando uso somente...
   height: calc(100% - 100px);
na div tudo, fica a lateral perfeita, aparecendo a faixa vermelha que coloquei lá. Fica faltando somente a parte da bottom, aonde não aparece a borda vermelha, a tela fica praticamente perfeita.
Ainda estou curioso. Mas isso me ajuda demais mesmo!

Comment: Não entendi bem o que está acontecendo, em qual elemento vc es´ta colocando essas regras ? Fiz uma edição com um exemplo do seu código...@PauloSérgioDuff qualquer coisa comenta que agente ajusta